# Internal Server Error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working with jupyter notebook through SSH (anaconda and python are on my linux machine but output in jupyter notebook I see on windows machine).
I tried to install keras and tensorflow but something went wrong and I removed these packages. After that I can't open any of my notebooks (but the file system output is okay, I can see all the folders and files in jupyter notebook).

Can you please help me to solve it? I think maybe it happened when tensorflow was removed, some packages also were deleted?

Comment: This could be caused by a lot of things. Are you tunneling the notebook, or are you actually running a browser from the Linux machine (displaying on Windows)? How did you install and uninstall Keras and Tensorflow? Did you restart the notebook server?

Comment: Tunneling the notebook. Install and removed via conda commands. No, I didn't restart the notebook but I have never had a problem like this before (with installing and uninstalling libraries).

Comment: I'd restart the notebook; packages may still slumber in the notebook memory, but if the actual files are gone, this will lead to an error.

Comment: thanks, restarting the notebook helped with this issue!